I can't seem to get all of the middleware while creating a new laravel project
I getting started with laravel so, i don't know much about it.
There is this youtube video i was following so far it was great  however when it got to the point where i have to use middlewares i found out that i don't have that folder in my project directory.

I have tried to re-create a new project,
i have uninstalled composer, php and laravel itself and re-installed them back again but it didn't work still.

i have searched all over the internet for solution couldn't find one thathelped
help me

If you're using Laravel 11, most of the middleware lives in the framework itself now. You can publish them if you need to modify them. See https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/releases#middleware

Thank you. this worked. the app.php file from bootstrap folder can be used to name or to call a middleware before that it can be used on a route

Middleware folder is present in app\Http\Middleware
It is not available in a fresh laravel install.
If you want to create your custom Middleware then you can use below command
php artisan make:middleware Authenticate

After running this command it will automatically create that folder with your middleware file inside it.
Please make sure to include your middleware in kernel file.

This was changed since Laravel 11 the Append.php has been removed and also prior to Laravel 11, you would typically never touch bootstrap/app.php. However, that is no longer the case in this new version.

To create a new middleware you would have to use the following command in termianal

php artisan make:middleware EnsureTokenIsValid

New middleware aliases can be created in app.php 
function (Middleware $middleware) {
    $middleware->alias([
        'some_key' => \App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddleware::class,
    ]);
}`enter code here`


your answer is good but please mention bootstrap/app.php
